# QWebEnginePage print to PDF doesn't print selectable text in the PDF like Google Chrome

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebengine, webengine

I'm trying to print an html document from a QWebEngineView by using the [print()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#print) method and a [QPrinter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprinter.html) instance that is required by this method.

The problem that I have is that in the resulting PDF I'm not able to select any text that is available. The PDF is somehow plain, just like a picture inside of the PDF file.
Considering that Qt's WebEngine is the same as the one from Chromium (Google Chrome), they should behave in the same way but on the PDFs exported from Chrome I'm able to select the text.
Is there a way to control how the pdf is exported?

P.S. I'm not using the [printToPdf()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#printToPdf) method because it generates a very big pdf (aprox. 5MB).

Comment: How exactly you print? whats your code for printing?

Comment: chrome uses different protocol for printing "chrome://print" which we have no access to it in QWebEngieView, at least in qml i am sure of it

Answer (score 0):

At the cost of page/pdf quality, you can inject the `QWebEngineView` page to html and load the html into `QTextDocument` that can be printed ..

```
webview->page()->toHtml([this](const QString& result){handlePagePrint(result);});

void handlePagePrint(QString result)
{
    QTextDocument td;
    td.setHtml(result);
    td.print(&printer);
}
```

Comment: this wont be the exact same page we want to see in print preview, because print style is different from pages style "which is specified in css".